# Why the image cannot be created using PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
im       = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
$dimgrey = imagecolorallocate($im,60,60,60);
$indigo  = imagecolorallocate($im,249,249,249);

@imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 370, 400, 400, $dimgrey);
@imagefill($im, 0, 0, $indigo);

$box = new Box($im,true);

$box->setFontFace(__DIR__.'/../../fonts/iransans/IRANSansWeb_Bold.ttf');
$box->setFontSize(TITLE_FONT_SIZE);
$box->setFontColor(new Color(10, 10, 10));
$box->setBox(15, 18, 360, 360);
$box->setTextAlign('center', 'top');
$box->draw($title);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

It will be shown like this:

[image]

Noted that, I guess the issue is because of "header". Because the image will be created as well when I replace

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

with:

```
ob_start (); 
imagepng($im, null, 9, PNG_ALL_FILTERS);
$image_data = ob_get_contents (); 
ob_end_clean (); 
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode ($image_data) . "' />";
```

But I don't like the second way .. any idea how can I do that using the first code?

Comment: You would have to figure out how your first excerpt intermingled the binary file data with textual residue e.g.

Comment: @mario Any idea how can I figure it out?

Comment: View source, save as, etc.

Comment: @mario When I remove that header `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`, it will be shown [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWssS.png). any clue?

Comment: @mario Also this is [View Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcdGs.png)

Comment: Try to dump the objects and commenting out all of the output lines, maybe something is triggering a warning or an error

Comment: What is `Box` for a class?

Comment: @odan Assume it's a class which adds some filters on the image.